# Handle NaN values in mean pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, nan

I calculated the average of the values contained in a column within my df as follows:

```
meanBpm = df['tempo'].mean()
```

the average is calculated for different days of the week and for some days the value I expect is returned, while for other days it returns NaN. This is because it is possible that the bpm (the tempo column) for a certain day is not there because for example I have not listened to any songs. I would like to replace these NaNs in ouput with a default value which could be 0 or -1

EDIT: i solved it, thanks a lot everyone for the replies

Comment: Are you sure you want to replace it or do you rather want to not take it into consideration when computing the mean. If you replace them, your mean will be skewed so to say. So for your bpm example, if you have [100, 100,100, 0] you would get a mean of 300/4 = 75, which I think would be wrong as you rather listen to 100 bpm on average.

Comment: Exactly what you said in the second point, I want to not take it into consideration when computing the mean. For example if I calculate the average of the bpm in the time slot between 7pm and 8pm and I have not listened to any songs I want the average to be 0 and not NaN

Comment: then u want to use .dropna() instead of .fillna(0)

Comment: i still have nan :(

Answer (score 0):

what your'e looking for is -

```
df['tempo'].fillna(0).mean()
```

Comment: i've tried as you suggested but in the output i still have nan.